# How do you test user flows that involve confirmation by email?

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, e2e-testing, cypress

I mean functional or E2E testing. That's all clear with generic flows, but when it comes to transactional emails (signup confirmations, password resets, purchase notifications and others) it's still bringing questions. After some research I came up with a few ideas. One is to leverage Restmail.net API (here examples with Selenium WebDriver and Cypress - http://dsheiko.com/weblog/testing-sign-up-flow-with-activation-by-email). It's free, but API is public. So it's not really suitable for email messages with potentially sensitive information. Another approach to access Gmail inbox via IMAP bridge or Gmail API (here the explanation and code snippets - https://docs.puppetry.app/testing-emails/example-with-imap-bridge). But again, it's rather a workaround.

I know there are guys like Sendgrid, Mailgun, Email Yak, Postmark. I don't want to pay that much. So how do you folks do it? It it a thing to you?

Comment: You could have a look at mailhog for outgoing emails: https://github.com/mailhog/MailHog, we currently test emails with cypress and the mailhog api.

Comment: Wow, looks great. So you have in-house mail server, which exposes API to access inbox. Besides QA-engineers can create as many user accounts as they want, right? And how do you poll it for email messages from tests? Something similar to my function?

Comment: I fiddled with MailHog a bit, that's even better than I expected. As I got it - one doesn't really need an exposed mail server, but simply run this tool in docker and configure sendmail on testing env to direct all the mails to MailHog. But it won't work then with Mailchimp-sent emails...

Comment: Our usecase seems to differ. We only test emails, that our service omits. Instead of using e.g. sendmail on localhost:25 we use Mailhog on localhost:1025 and query the emitted emails using the Mailhog API. I have not used mailchimp, but I would probably just test the triggers and API responses, etc. because - in my opinion - you don't want/need to test the mailchimp API (should be tested already).

Comment: No, I don't. We have a service that handles API requests like email activation. The only way to get the generated activation link - it's from the sent out email message. And the message is sent by using Mailchimp. That's why I'm considering ways to read the inbox for the message

Answer (score 5):

We're doing this using [Mailosaur](https://mailosaur.com/) email addresses for our test users.  We then use a cypress custom command to [query Mailosaur for the expected email](https://docs.mailosaur.com/reference#search-for-messages).  It was super easy to set up.

Here's the main part of that custom command, which is all we had to add to start doing email testing.  You can refer to their API docs for what `query`, `mailosaurServer`, and `MailosaurApiKey` should be.

```
Cypress.Commands.add("getEmailFromMailService", query => {
  return cy
    .request({
      method: "POST",
      url: `https://mailosaur.com/api/messages/await?server=${mailosaurServer}`,
      body: query,
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      auth: { user: mailosaurApiKey },
    })
    .then(response => {
      expect(response.status).to.equal(200);
      return response.body;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a post request for the "forgot your password" and then assert on it.

something like:

```
    cy.visit('yoursite')
    cy.get('#forgotpassword').click().then(function (xhr) {
    cy.server()
    cy.request('POST', 'APIforForgotPassword').as('sucessfullemail)
    })
    cy.get(@sucessfullemail).then(function (xhr) {
    expect(xhr.status).to.eq(200)
```

Comment: Do you mean "APIforForgotPassword" is some exposed API that can be used to retrieve the token required for resetting password?

Comment: When you inspect your web page you can see the API

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get. So, let's say I have a web-app to test. I make Cypress to navigate to login page, click "Forgot your password?", type in email, click submit. After that the web-app generate a URL with some access token and sends me mail message. So I can get the dedicated URL only by email (that's the whole point - to ensure the account really belongs to me). So the question was - how you get it from the automated test cases

Answer (score 0):

```
Cypress.Commands.add('ConfirmUser', () => {
  const confirmationToken = null;
  cy.request({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/confirmation_token?email=test_user@cypress.com',
    followRedirect: false
  })
    .then((resp) => {
      confirmationToken = resp.token
    })
  cy.visit('/en/confirmation?confirmation_token=token')
})
```

Create the API that requires the email as a parameter and returns the confirmation-token. call the API from cypress commands as ajax-request and get the response token